# Facebook iOS SDK 3.5 modal feed dialog loads empty in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

I use this code to present share dialog:

```
if (![[FBSession activeSession] isOpen]) {[self login]; return;}

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"name", @"name",
                                       @"caption", @"caption",
                                       @"description", @"description",
                                       @"http://cnn.com", @"link",
                                       @"http://cnn.com/.png", @"picture",
                                       nil];

  [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:
     ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
         } else {
             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                 NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing (clicked the 'x' icon)");
             } else {
                 // Handle the publish feed callback
                 NSLog(@"Handle the publish feed callback");
             }
         }
     }];
```

I have added proper entries (required according to sdk docs) to the Info.plist:

[image]

and AppDelegate methods handling facebook redirections as well:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                    fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                        NSLog(@"In fallback handler");
                    }];
}

-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application{

    [FBSession.activeSession close];

}
```

I also added frameworks required by iOS Facebook 3.5.1 SDK:

[image]

**It gives empty dialog box** (on both - real device and simulator) with loading indicator spinning forever:

[image]

There is no error shown in logs, etc... and I can easily dismiss it (with correct handler log).

I asume FBSession is started and opened correctly (I can authorise successfully through redirection to Safari and get back to the app - which makes me think redirections works fine).

Why is that happening? What am I missing? And BTW: Why there are no error logs?

This is so frustrating as I have been implementing facebook integration many times before but in this app I wanted to try the newest SDK which is advertized as: 'to be easy as never before'.

Comment: Have you added the FacebookDisplayName parameter to your plist file?
Check the upgrade doc here:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.2-to-3.5/


Also, Can you compare your code with any of our samples which do the same thing. There are a couple of samples which are part of the SDK and then you can look at separate how-to's here(https://github.com/fbsamples).

Comment: Yes. I have added FacebookDisplayName as well as FacebookAppID to the info.plist. And I use code snippets based on iOS SDK samples.

Comment: I see. Does it reproduce if you have a valid session? Also if you're passing a nil session, you must be authenticating on a webview, correct? And after the webview login, you get this blank screen?

Comment: Yes, I am authenticated correctly and redirected back to the app successfully and then I get this black modal share screen in both cases: when I pass nil for a ssession of [FBSession activeSession]. Should be the same anyway.

Comment: Having the same issue on mobile device, not on simulator. Would prefer a solution that does not involve using ShareKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com) and follow installation instructions from here: http://getsharekit.com/install/

It usually works out of the box.

Comment: It may not be direct solution, but after struggling way tooo long with this issue I decided (in desperation) to follow your advice. It worked like a charm and I got twitter and other sharing options for free.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the activeSession as parameter to the feed dialog?:

```
//...
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:[FBSession activeSession]
                                       parameters:params
                                          handler:
^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
//...
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried it in one of my first attempts to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then check if you have permissions to publish, if not, ask for them:

```
if([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound){
   [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                         defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone
                                       completionHandler:
                                       ^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {

                                        if (!error) {
                                            //Here call your method to publish again so you have granted the active session has publish permissions.
                                        }
             }];
```

I haven't done with the web feed dialog, so let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same problem. But eventually this error was caused by @"picture" key in the params dictionary. So my advice is to replace you params dictionary with dictionary from Facebook examples

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Sharing Tutorial", @"name",
                                   @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
                                   @"Allow your users to share stories on Facebook from your app using the iOS SDK.", @"description",
                                   @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/", @"link",
                                   @"http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png", @"picture",
                                   nil];
```

and then step by step figure out which from your dictionary keys leads to blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

Here I experienced the same problem. My solution is:

**1.** On **AppDelegate** Remove `[FBAppEvents activateApp];
[FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActive];`
From `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` and 
`[FBSession.activeSession close];` from `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *) application` as well

**2.** Put Display name on info.plist along with the FB Id.

**3.**  Remove your old framework and then add the new framework v3.15.1 (Latest). Keep mind to  mark **copy items into destination group's folder** and **add targets** as well.